# Poles, wavefunctions, transmission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition

Why is it said that $\operatorname{sech}x$ (a transmission amplitude) has a simple pole on the imaginary axis?

Comment: Can you give some context? sech has no poles as far as I can tell, as it is a continuous, strictly positive, bound function. I would vote down but I can't.

Comment: @adavid, the imaginary axis!  The poles are on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Thanks @user1631. When I see $x$, I think $\mathbb{R}$. I guess $z$ would have got me on the right track. And next time, please do give some more context...

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/75756/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a [simple pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29) at $a$ means that $f(z) \sim 1/(z-a)^{n}$, with $n=1$. I.e., the function does not diverge with $1/z^2$ or a larger power.

For more details on the poles of $\operatorname{sech}(z)$, check out [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/example-of-a-simple-pole). As simple as the poles of $\operatorname{sech}(z)$ may be, there is an infinite amount of them (as many as there are zeroes to $\operatorname{cosh}(z)$).